# Location of installed client libraries in cloudshell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-client

I have installed Speech to text client libraries in my cloud shell.

```
pip3 install google-cloud-speech
```

However,when I check in the path

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud
```

There is no speech to text client libraries. I want to know where it is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it is installed in
$HOME/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud